# Why docker-compose doesn't start all containers described in the file?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.19.8
    container_name: reverse-proxy-container
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/config:/etc/nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  sheet-service:
    image: sheetservice:latest
    build:
      context: ./microservices/sheet-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: sheet-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "nginx-reverse-proxy"
```

only `sheet-service` container starts, when executing the docker script with the command `docker-compose up --build`. When I check the running processes by typing `docker ps -a` the output shows this [image]. The name of container strangely is not `sheet-service` as specified in `docker-compose.yml`.

The `Dockerfile` of `sheet-service`:

```
FROM node:14.15.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run start
```

The script's starting logs:

```
> docker-compose up --build
Building sheet-service
Sending build context to Docker daemon  73.29MB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:14.15.0
 ---> b90fa0d7cbd1
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6ce9a5a77956
Step 3/6 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d9c528ab2b74
Step 4/6 : RUN npm ci --only=production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 221d8f411055
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 025dba9ebb44
Step 6/6 : RUN npm run start
 ---> Running in 84c8c1b8a9d8

> sheet-service@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node src/index.js

Server running on port 3002!
```

If I comment out the lines where the `sheet-service` is defined like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword

      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.19.8
    container_name: reverse-proxy-container
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/config:/etc/nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  # sheet-service:
  #   image: sheetservice:latest
  #   build:
  #     context: ./microservices/sheet-service
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   container_name: sheet-service
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   ports:
  #     - 3002:3002
  #   depends_on:
  #     - "db"
  #     - "nginx-reverse-proxy"
```

all other containers start successfully. Why `sheet-service` stop other containers from running and why it shows with different than specified name?

If I run containers one by one with `docker-compose run container_name` all containers start successfully without errors or warnings.

`docker-compose config`:

```
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
    restart: unless-stopped
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
    - published: 5432
      target: 5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/myuser/Coding/myproject/data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverse-proxy-container
    image: nginx:1.19.8
    ports:
    - published: 8000
      target: 8000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/myuser/Coding/myproject/proxy/config:/etc/nginx:rw
  sheet-service:
    build:
      context: /home/myuser/Coding/myproject/microservices/sheet-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: sheet-service
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
      nginx-reverse-proxy:
        condition: service_started
    image: sheetservice:latest
    ports:
    - published: 3002
      target: 3002
    restart: unless-stopped
version: '2'
```

`Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350`
`docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2`
`Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS`

Comment: What have you done to figure out the problem yourself? What do the logs/stdout show ads you run the ``docker-compose up``? If looks like all your containers are independent of each other - but we don't know what your sheetservice container does.

Comment: The logs could be essential information - they are usually the first place to look. As you point out, sheetservice does depend on the other two, so if you say sheetservice started then that would imply the other two services must have started first? When I said 'independent' I was not clear - I meant in the sense that it does not appear as if (for example) nginx *can only* start if the db starts. I don't know what adminer or sheetservice do - for all I know they could be responsible for killing the db and nginx services??? The logs would provide more information.

Comment: I downvote this question, because you a) refused to provide your logs for no visible reason after being asked to do so and b) don't really share valuable information: we don't know what all these services (okay, postgres is fine) do. At least logs and dockerfiles should be provided, also some source code that is referenced in logs (errors? I cannot see it!) may be useful. Don't "spare [us] the unessential information", it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've posted the logs and Dockerfile. From the logs is evident that there are no errors. I don't get it how the docker container starts successfully, with no errors, when it depends on two other which obviously don't start. The `docker ps -a` shows only one container as I mentiouned above.

Comment: Perhaps the problem might be with compatability between  `docker-compose` and `docker` versions?

Comment: In your sheet-service you have a ``RUN npm run start`` command - isn't that starting the node server as part of the docker build? you only want to start the node server as part of the docker //run// and so that should be a ``CMD`` or ``ENTRYPOINT`` in the ``Dockerfile`` I think?

Comment: Many thanks, @JohnXF!!! That fixed the issue! You can post an answer below and I will accept it to make it visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile ...

```
FROM node:14.15.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .

RUN npm run start
```

... contains a last line of `RUN npm run start`. This `RUN` instruction is carried out as part of the docker image build and starts the node server - the build will then 'hang' while that stays running and thus cause subsequent steps in the docker compose startup not to ever start (never mind complete).

I presume you mean to execute the node process as part of the actual docker *container* startup process and so you should change your `RUN npm run start` line to be an `ENTRYPOINT npm run start` as that will make the node startup process execute when the container starts.